# Laravel accessors are giving json object the information twice

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, eloquent

So, I have a model named product. This product has a foreign key to a cpu (cpu_id) which is another model, and contains all the information about the cpu.
When casting this model (product) to a JSON object, I only get the cpu_id, instead of all the information of the cpu (I have defined the relation already, and it works). 
So I created an accessor called 'cpu_details'. Now, when I cast the product to json, I get the info about the cpu doubled: from the cpu, and the newly defined cpu_details. Why is this happening? Is there a way for json to automatically get the info about the cpu?

My Product model

```php
 class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product';
    protected $appends = ['cpu_details'];

    public function getCpuDetailsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->cpu;
    }

    public function cpu()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Specs\CPU');
    }
}
```

My product when cast to json (using the toJson() function) without the accessor, notice that i only get the cpu_id, but not the cpu itself, but it gets info from other relations like the discounts (another model).

```js
{id: 18, 
stock: 10,
cpu_id: 2,
discounts: Array(1)
0: {id: 5, val: "0.5", begindate: "2019-07-04", enddate: "2021-07-16"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
}
```

Now this is what I get when i cast to json, with the accessor, now i get the information twice

```js
{id: 19, 
stock: 10
cpu: {id: 2, freq: "12", cores: 4, threads: 8, name: "Apple A12Z Bionic"}
cpu_details: {id: 2, freq: "12", cores: 4, threads: 8, name: "Apple A12Z Bionic"}
cpu_id: 2
discounts: discounts: Array(1)
0: {id: 4, val: "0.4", begindate: "2018-06-14", enddate: "2021-06-18"}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `cpu_details` you need to load the relationship `cpu` which will be attached to your Product object. If you only need the cpu details, you should eager load the relationship and call your product object like this:

```
Product::with('cpu')->get();
```

Now if for some reason you really want to load the cpu_details and not see the cpu, you can as well hide the `cpu` from your JSON by using:

```
protected $hidden = ['cpu'];
```

Comment: That's perfect, worked great! Thank you so much.
Additionally: is there any way to load that by default? Meaning: every time I get a Product, the cpu will eager load.

Comment: You can! just use `protected $with = ['cpu'];`

Comment: Exactly what I neeeded! Thanks again :D